# jquery empty() won't clean div contents

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I'm loading a slider into with the .load.  For some reason once I've loaded the slider into the div I can't clear it out.  I'm trying to use the jquery empty() function but it won't work.  The js I'm using to load the slider in is:

```
$("#nav").click(function() {
    $("#info_header").empty();
    $("#content_1").empty();
    $("#content_2").empty();
    $("#content_3").empty();
    $("#images").empty();
    $("#load_container").switchClass("load_container_port", "load_container_slider", .01);
    $("#controls").switchClass("controls_port", "controls_slider", .01);
    $("#info").switchClass("info_port", "info_slider", .01);
    $("#load_container").css({
        height:($(window).width() * 500) /1000
    });
    $("#info").css({
        height:($(window).width() * 500) /1000
    });
    $("#top_section").css({
        height:(($(window).width() * 500) /1000) + 40
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#slider").delay(100).load("home_slider.html"); 
    }, .03);       
});
```

and then the js I'm using to try empty and load new content in is:

```
function portfolio_clear() {   
    $('#slider').empty(); 
    $("#images").empty();
    $("#load_container").switchClass("load_container_slider", "load_container_port", .01);
    $("#controls").switchClass("controls_slider", "controls_port", .01);
    $("#info").switchClass("info_slider", "info_port", .01);
}


$("#space").click(function() {

    $('#load_container').css({
        background: "#191919"
    });
    $('#close_white').css({
        display: "inline-block"
    });
    $('#close_black').css({
        display: "none"
    });
    $('#goto_white').css({
        display: "inline-block"
    });
    $('#goto_black').css({
        display: "none"
    });

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("#info_header").load(id + "_header.txt");
    $("#content_1").load(id + "_1.txt");
    $("#content_2").load(id + "_2.txt");
    $("#content_3").load(id + "_3.txt");

    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://www.klossal.com/space.jpg"
    }).appendTo("#images");

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300);

    if (screen.width >= 1025) {
        $("#top_section").animate({
            height: 1112
        }, 300);
    }
    else {
        $("#top_section").animate({
            height: 926
        }, 300);
    }

});
```

the page can be viewed here:

"http://173.254.28.83/~klossalc/index_test.html"

you can load the slider by clicking klossal.com in the very upper left hand corner, and you can try to click on the first tile below to try to replace it, which won't work.  If you click on the tiles first they load fine, and then clicking klossal.com to load the slider also works, just not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this to clear an elements html:

```
$("#element_id").html('');
```

I cant see where you are calling portfolio_clear() from, if you want it to happen when you click your thumbnails try this:

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
        portfolio_clear();
        $(".thumb_info").not(this).switchClass("info_color_3", "info_color_2", 300);
        $(this).find('.thumb_info').switchClass("info_color_2", "info_color_3", 300);
    });
```

Comment: just tried that, it didn't work, I have no idea why it won't unload this div

Comment: works if I do it through the console let me look through your js

Comment: Where is portfolio clear being called from, I cant see it in your script, should it not be part of the thumbs click event handler?

Comment: I made it a function of it's own cause if I can get this to work it'll be called at teh begining of each thumb click event

Comment: there's an event for teh thumb click and then I made individual functions for each thumb specifically.  The "space" thumb is the only one right now with the portfolioclear being called right now

Comment: http://173.254.28.83/~klossalc/home_slider.html  that's the slider that's getting loaded in with .load that wont' go away

Comment: portfolio is getting called from $("#space").click(function() {

Comment: I have looked through this function $("#space").click(function() {  there is no call to portfolio_clear(); in fact there is no call to it anywhere in your javascript, nor in the output html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20637/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-webweaverd)